# Property 'getDate' does not exist on type 'CalendarOptions'.ts(2339)

Tags: angular, date, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am trying to retrieve back the current month and year of my calendar however I get an error message which says "Property 'getDate' does not exist on type 'CalendarOptions'.ts(2339)". I am using this calendar https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-getDate. I have followed the instructions, although I am using typescript and the instructions are in javascript.

```
getDate() {
  const getDates = this.calendarOptions.getDate();
}
```

there is an error underline on the `.getDate();`. I have looked at the API and the method does exist in the package.

below is the calendar initialization

```
calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
plugins: [ dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin],
initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
headerToolbar: {
  left: 'prev,next', 
  center: 'title', 
  right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay' 
},
dateClick: this.handleDateClick.bind(this), 
events: []
};
```

Comment: The object you create in the initialisation doesn't have a `getDate` method. It's all very well telling TS it's supposed to be a `CalendarOptions` instance, but if you don't somehow create all the necessary fields, it won't work. Can you instantiate with `new`?

Comment: Your `CalendarOptions` object appears to just be a simple object. It's not an instance of fullCalendar as far as I can see. Are you passing this data into fullCalendar somewhere? As per the setup instructions (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-es6) somewhere you should be writing `var calendar = new Calendar(`... it's that `calendar` object which would have the `getDate()` method.

Comment: Or, since you tagged with Angular, then if you're using fullCalendar's ready-made Angular component (it wasn't clear if you are or not, from your description), then the documentation for that tells you how to get the calendar object via the getApi() method of the component - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/angular in the section entitled "Calendar API".

Comment: I have tried adding getDate within the calendarOptions object, however, it still shows an error of 'type plugin not accessible to type calendarOptions'

I have tried adding new Calendar however it throws a bunch of errors 'an argument for el was not provided'. i dont think new Calendar is accessible in angular. I have had a look at the documentation but it does not mention how to get current date.
When i got into the calendar APi in 'main.d.ts' I can see the getDate() method but i canbt access it.